# Here is some error with my .h file which show [Error] unterminated #ifndef when I include my class template in it

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, constructor

**Header file**

```
#ifndef WIKI_H
#define WIKI_H

template<class T>

class Rectangle
{

    private:

        T length;
        T breadth;

        void printarea();

        public:

            Rectangle();
};
```

**source file**

```
#include "Wiki.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Rectangle::printarea()
{

    cout<< "Area = " << length*breadth <<endl; 
}

Rectangle::Rectangle()
{

    cout<< "Enter Length" <<endl;
    cin>> lenght;
    cout<< "Enter Breadth" <<endl;
    cin>> breadth;

    printarea();
}
```

**main file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Wiki.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Rectangle<int>X;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're missing an `#endif`

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: `lenght` => `length`

Answer (score 12):

You need to add a `#endif` to the end of your header file.

Comment: After I corrected mistake in my header and source file still the compiler show the error - undefined reference to `Rectangle<int>::Rectangle()'

Comment: @Utsav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: For anyone arriving here who is thinking 'I have an #endif but this error is still showing', it can also be caused by circular include statements.